# What is $\int \frac {e^x} {e^{2x} + 2e^x + 1} \, dx.$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals

What is $$\int \frac {e^x} {e^{2x} + 2e^x + 1} \, dx.$$

[Wolfram Alpha gives:](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2F%28e%5E2x+%2B+2e%5Ex+%2B+1%29) `no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions`.

I get $$\log (e^x+1) + \frac 1 {e^x+1}$$ (proof below).  My work seems correct to me, but it's different than $\frac {-1} {e^x+1}$ I've seen elsewhere (without explanation).  Am I correct? If not, where is my error?

Let $$u(x) = e^x\\
f(x) = \frac {x} {(x+1)^2}\\
\int f(x) \, dx = \log{(x +1)} \, + \frac 1 {x+1}$$
the last of which is [verified here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2).  Then

$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac {e^x} {e^{2x} + 2e^x + 1} \, dx &= \int \frac {e^x} {(e^x + 1)^2} \, dx \\
&= \int f(u(x)) \cdot u'(x) \, dx \\
&= \log (e^x+1) + \frac 1 {e^x+1}.
\end{align*}$$

but this is different than $\frac {-1} {e^x+1}$.

Comment: The substitution $t=e^x+1$ gives $\int t^{-2}\,dt=-t^{-1}$

Comment: $\frac{e^x}{(e^x + 1)^2}$ would only be $f(u(x))$ and not $f(u(x)) \cdot u'(x)$. The $f$ you should have taken is $f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$.

Comment: Is it $e^2x$ or $e^{2x}$ in the denominator?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2F%28e%5E%7B2x%7D+%2B+2e%5Ex+%2B+1%29) does give the antiderivative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Bruno B, the error is that if you let $u = e^x$, then you have to note that $du = e^xdx$, and so the integral is
$$\int\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}du=-\frac{1}{u+1}+C=-\frac{1}{e^x+1}+C$$

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments by @RyszardSzwarc, one has:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x} + 2e^{x} + 1}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{x} + 1)}{(e^{x} + 1)^{2}} = -\frac{1}{1 + e^{x}} + C
\end{align*}